# IOException: Could not initialize SSL context - Apache Commons Net - Android

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I'm trying to connect to a FTP using Apaches FTPSClient but I keep getting this error:

06-15 09:15:14.749: W/System.err(29451): java.io.IOException: Could not initialize SSL context

This happens with the following code, the error comes on the second line (connect).

```
ftpsClient = new FTPSClient("SSL");
ftpsClient.connect(host);
int reply = ftpsClient.getReplyCode();
if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    ftpsClient.disconnect();
}
ftpsClient.login(user, password + nl);
ftpsClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftpsClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT:

full stacktrace

```
06-15 09:15:14.749: W/System.err(29451): java.io.IOException: Could not initialize SSL context
06-15 09:15:14.749: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.initSslContext(FTPSClient.java:228)
06-15 09:15:14.749: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:246)
06-15 09:15:14.749: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:197)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:164)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:184)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:273)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doWhat(FTPClient.java:546)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doInBackground(FTPClient.java:201)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doInBackground(FTPClient.java:1)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-15 09:15:14.757: W/System.err(29451):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451): Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException: No X509KeyManager found
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl.<init>(SSLParametersImpl.java:116)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:92)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:219)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.initSslContext(FTPSClient.java:226)
06-15 09:15:14.765: W/System.err(29451):    ... 14 more
```

EDIT2:
exception with keymanager

```
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:257)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:263)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:197)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:164)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:184)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:273)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doWhat(FTPClient.java:552)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doInBackground(FTPClient.java:203)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doInBackground(FTPClient.java:1)
06-15 10:45:14.886: W/System.err(32467):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-15 10:45:14.894: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-15 10:45:14.894: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-15 10:45:14.901: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-15 10:45:14.901: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-15 10:45:14.901: W/System.err(32467):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-15 10:45:14.901: W/System.err(32467): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
06-15 10:45:14.909: W/System.err(32467):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
06-15 10:45:14.909: W/System.err(32467):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
06-15 10:45:14.909: W/System.err(32467):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
06-15 10:45:14.909: W/System.err(32467):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:463)
06-15 10:45:14.909: W/System.err(32467):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
06-15 10:45:14.917: W/System.err(32467):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBytes(OutputStreamWriter.java:167)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:158)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:124)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:477)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sendCommand(FTPSClient.java:486)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:537)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:586)
06-15 10:45:14.925: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.syst(FTP.java:1504)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.getSystemType(FTPClient.java:2074)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2511)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2275)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doWhat(FTPClient.java:298)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doInBackground(FTPClient.java:205)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at com.test.FTPClient$getFileListTask.doInBackground(FTPClient.java:1)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-15 10:45:14.933: W/System.err(32467):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: For some reason it's not finding a valid KeyManager. On what device/Android version are you running this? Also try `new FTPSClient("TLS");` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: On a Galaxy Nexus 4.0.4. I've tried TLS too but the same thing happens. Also if I declare Implicit or Explicit, and a port. 
Valid KeyManager? Thats new to me.

Comment: A KeyManager is needed if your sever requires client authentication. Does yours require it? If not, it should work. You can try to set one yourself. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason it cannot create the default `KeyManager` and that's why initializing the SSL context is failing. Try to install the default one manually. Something like:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(null, null);
KeyManager km = kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];

ftpsClient = new FTPSClient("SSL");
ftpsClient.setKeyManager(km);
```

Comment: That produces another crash, I added the stack trace above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your server really require SSL? On what port? Does it require client authentication?

Comment: At the moment I'm testing against this server: http://www.secureftp-test.com/ which requires it. And it works fine with the same settings on FileZilla.

Comment: OK, but the server is closing the connection, so it's either expecting something you are not sending, or it times out. Does the error happen right away? Did you set the implicit flag?

Comment: It has started to work over Explicit protocol now but not the Implicit, then I get the same error as before. While testing I removed the port and Implicit setting and that was what was wrong with the Explicit mode + missing keymanager that you suggested. But I have no idea about the Implicit one. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to use implicit mode? Does the test site support it? If it does, there might be some additional configuration needed.